# Accidentally ran sudo rm /* on my Arch Linux installation

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, rm, data-recovery

I accidentally executed `sudo rm /*` instead of `sudo rm ./*` inside a directory whose contents I wanted to delete, and I have basically messed up my system.

None of the basic commands like `ls`, `grep` etc. are working, and none of my applications are opening, like chromium, slack, image viewer etc.

I tried to look up my problem on the internet and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/accidentally-executed-sudo-rm-on-a-remote-server) question, but none of the solutions there work for me.

I am on an Arch Linux desktop, and I haven't logged out of my system since this happened, because I'm afraid I won't be able to log back in, as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18370/454328). Also, I don't have a live USB of an Arch Linux image file, if that helps.

Any help on how should I proceed further to make my system go back to normal, would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I'm attaching the outputs of some commands:

```
$ echo /*

/boot /dev /etc /home /lost+found /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var
```

```
$ echo /usr/*

/usr/bin /usr/include /usr/lib /usr/lib32 /usr/lib64 /usr/local /usr/sbin /usr/share /usr/src
```

Also,
`echo /usr/bin/*` gives me a long list of directories in the format `/usr/bin/{command}` where {command} is any command that I could have run from the terminal had I not messed my system up.

Please let me know if any other information is needed!

Comment: Are you sure "rm /*" was the command you executed?  On this system here, I don't have a single file in /, and "rm /*" wouldn't have removed directories.  With the symptoms you describe, "rm -r /*" looks a more likely culprit.  Your only option is recovery from backup.  In the future, pay attention when executing as root.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yeah, I had executed `rm /*`, and the directories haven't been deleted in `/`, just the files. Hope that helps.

Comment: "ls" isn't working in the same session that executed the "rm"?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes, "ls" is not working in the same session. Executing "ls" gave me an error: `usr/bin/ls: there is no such directory`

Comment: As others have commented, it's very strange that you lost commands like `ls` by only removing files from /. To understand what's lost, list the contents of essential directories with `echo /*; echo /bin/*; echo /usr/bin/*` etc.

Comment: @berndbausch I have updated my question with some more details. Do let me know if more information is needed!

Comment: The only things that would be removed by that command in a modern Arch installation would be the `/usr` symlinks (`bin -> usr/bin`, `lib -> usr/lib`, `lib64 -> usr/lib`, `sbin -> usr/bin`). Not sure what difference those would make. Maybe the linker is assumed to be in `/lib`?

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/ls`? Can you use `/usr/bin/ln` to create a symlink or does that complain about missing `/lib`?

Comment: @terdon I am unable to run either `/usr/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/ln`. Both give me the same "bash: /usr/bin/ls(or ln): No such file or directory" error

Comment: @terdon Also, did you delete your answer for some reason?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my answer because I realized that it wouldn't work. Use [stefan0xC's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640359/22222) instead: boot into a live session, mount the local drive and then re-create the symlinks. Alternatively, try `/usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ln -s /usr/lib /lib64` which could also work.

Comment: @terdon ld.so might require a --library-path parameter for the same reasons

Comment: What happens when you run /usr/sbin/ldconfig?   It is statically linked.

Comment: You're going to need to use a rescue cd basically. Once you've booted that, I'd suggest backing up your home directory, and anything else you consider 'important' as it may get over written, then re-do the install. If you're lucky, you'll be able to bring back the old system without entirely wiping out all your configs.

Comment: Despite of the good answer given https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640359/320598 this reminds me of some old saying: Question: "What can I do if I executed `rm -r /`and I don't have a backup?" Answer: "Cry!"

Comment: Why do you say `echo /usr/bin/*` gives you a long list of _directories_? Did you mean _files_? (I ask because it looks like a typo, but if you actually do mean directories, that drastically changes the nature of what presumably happened to your system.)

Answer (score 51):

Arch Linux has four symbolic links in `/`:

- `bin -> usr/bin`
- `lib -> usr/lib`
- `lib64 -> usr/lib`
- `sbin -> usr/bin`

You should be able to recreate them (using a Live-USB or an emergency shell) or by calling the linker (with root privileges and in `/` as working directory) directly:

```
/usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ln -s usr/lib lib64
```

This should restore basic functionality in your running system. Then restoring the other symbolic links should be easy.

If you don't have root privileges you can reboot into a [recovery shell](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_troubleshooting#Recovery_shells) and fix the problems there.

**Why does `/usr/bin/ls` and other commands fail?**

Without the `/lib64` symbolic link dynamically linked programs will not find the dynamic linker/loader because the path is hardcoded to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (c.f. `ldd /usr/bin/ln`).

Comment: Running the command `/usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ln -s usr/lib lib64` gives me `/usr/bin/ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib64': Permission Denied` and running it with `sudo` gives me the same `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory` error. Is there any other alternative, since I don't currently have a live usb?

Comment: @ShreyTripathi reboot, you'll end up in an emergency root shell where you can mount the root partition and fix the problem. You can't run use this with `sudo` since the setuid binaries don't work that way, so you have no effective way of getting root now if you don't have a root shell open already.

Comment: And this is why I used to keep a set of statically linked tools in /proc/1/fd/10/bin until systemd broke it. It only took up 2mb of RAM.

Comment: @muru does that *work*? Can you use a /proc FD entry as a directory, if it's an open directory?

Comment: @user253751 Yeah. You can try it in the terminal with this: `ruby -e 'Dir.open "/"; Process.kill :STOP, Process.pid'; ls -l /proc/$(pgrep -nP $$ ruby)/fd/*/; kill %`

Comment: Thanks, it saved my day.

Comment: BTW (because this answer is only for an Arch system): for this to work on a Debian (or Debian-based?) system it needs to be slightly different due to their different directory-layout. There it is: `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ln -s usr/lib64 lib64`

Answer (score -8):

Correct your PATH variable, so that it points only to existing directories

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Then recreate the symlinks as shown by terdon's answer.

Then try a login from another terminal.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work. The system needs the `/lib64` symlink so `ln` won't work even if you change your path or use the full path to the `ln` command. That's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @terdon could you not work round that with LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @PhilipCouling maybe, I don't really know. But that isn't what this answer suggests. This is the same as simply using the full path to the executable and that won't solve anything.

Comment: @terdon absolutely.  I was more suggesting a way you might fix your own answer. I wasn't sure if you'd ruled it out though.

Comment: Yep, If you also set an appropriate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the libraries should be found by the executables.  I might be forgetting something else which is necessary so I wouldn't give it a 100% chance, but at least 95% ;-)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to try, just keep a recovery USB or CD at hand. I will, but not before tomorrow evening.

Comment: @Alfe: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can't help with the ELF interpreter (dynamic linker) itself; that comes straight from ELF metadata because the kernel has to load it as part of `execve`.  From `readelf -a /bin/ls` on my Arch GNU/Linux system, `Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  And `/lib64` is a symlink.  (The ld-linux...so dynamic linker is what checks for an LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var in the first place.)  So TL:DR: unless you have a statically linked busybox or `ln`, using absolute paths can't help you.  Except for running ld-linux.so *on* an executable.

Comment: It looks as if that wasn't a very bright idea from Arch.