# I accidentally typed sudo rm /* resulting in loss of "ls" and possibly other commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rm, data-recovery

I am a beginner and for deleting the files in the directory tried to use `sudo rm /` after which I said that it couldn't delete `/home`, etc. On seeing the files I realized that I just passed in the command to delete the root directory. And now I cant even use `ls`. Please help me in solving this.

```
shreyas@shreyas-OptiPlex-990:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/BITSAT_Sample_Test$ sudo rm /*
[sudo] password for shreyas: 
rm: cannot remove '/boot': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/cdrom': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/dev': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/etc': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/home': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/lost+found': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/media': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/mnt': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/proc': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/root': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/run': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/snap': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/srv': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/sys': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/tmp': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/usr': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/var': Is a directory
shreyas@shreyas-OptiPlex-990:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files(x86)/BITSAT_Sample_Test$ ls
bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640343/173368 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18362/173368

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity thankfully it isn’t; only the symlinks in `/` were deleted.

Comment: @Haxiel could you tell me what must be done after i have used a live USB (My recovery mode is also faulty )

Comment: @StephenKitt right! I misinterpreted the command as if had the `-r`.

Comment: please guide me I am desperate ...

Comment: @ShreyasDevesh From a live USB, you would 1) mount the filesystem from the host machine as read-write, and then 2) use the `ln` command to recreate the missing symlinks. The details are in the QA I have linked before.